# ajax.jquery With IE

Tags: jquery

I am using :

```
function ajax(u,s,t) {
jQuery.ajax({type: "POST", url: u, data: query, success: function(msg) { if(t==':eval') eval(msg); else document.getElementById(t).innerHTML=msg; } });
}
```

This works fine with FF but with IE it doesn't work is there somthing wrong I did?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what error message do you get, how does it not work?

Comment: Why are you using document.getElementById if you are using jQuery? I suspect that's working differently between the two browsers, you'd be better off using `$(t)` to identify the DOM object you are looking to manipulate and then doing so using jQuery. I suggest some more research on jQuery and the jQuery.ajax examples out there. Also, where does `t` come from?

Comment: Am using it to fill a dropdown onchange on another dropdown but the dropdown didn't filled on IE .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery why are you still manipulating the DOM manually? Try cleaning your code. Also there are strange things in your success callback. What is this `t` variable? Once you are using it as element ID and also testing it's value for `eval`. By the way you should avoid using `eval`.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: u,
    data: query,
    success: function(msg) {
        // This success callback needs revision
        if(t == ':eval') {
            // ??????
            eval(msg);
        }
        else {
            jQuery('#' + t).html(msg);
        }
    } 
});
```

I would probably replace all this with the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function:

```
$('#' + t).load(u, query);
```